# The story of Goddess Nimishamba

Tags: identification-request, devi, durga, parvati

I have visited a temple in Paris, Chennai Where the presiding deity is Devi Nimishamba,

I wanted to know the History of God and found Wikipedia which mentions

> Goddess Nimishamba is considered the incarnation of Goddess Parvathi, the consort of Lord Shiva. This place Ganjam is considered a holy place. Maharaja of Somavamsha Aryakshatriya performed penance at Nimishamba Temple. Shrichakra is carved on a stone in front of Sri Nimishamba and pooja is performed. There is a belief that Goddess Nimishamba is going to remove all the problems and troubles of her devotees within a minute. That is why she is called Nimishamba. Nimisha means a minute and Amba is the name of Parvathi. Somavamsha Aryakshatriya Mutharasa king Muktharaja was blessed with the boon that Sri Nimishamba will come to his aid in his fight against the demons in a minute. That is why there is a deity Lord Shiva by the name of Moukthikeshwara. This temple was installed at the time of Mummadi Krishnaraja Wodeyar about 300 to 400 years ago.

What is the exact story of Nimishamba, I would want to know the story fully.

What is the ShriChakra as mentioned in the text?